# Autosizing images in xamarin forms layouts

Tags: xamarin.forms

i'm very new to xamarin forms so, sorry if i ask obvious question.
I need to build a frame with labels and pictures within. It should look like the following

[image: the desired result]

By now i tried this:

```
<Frame OutlineColor="#2e5982"
    BackgroundColor="#2e5982"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Margin="0">
    <Frame.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="LbSecsHead" Font="Arial" TextColor="White" Text="Status" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Accent">
                        <Image x:Name="SignalSec6" Source="{local:ImageResource Fusion.Pictures.GreenSignalMaterialOff.png}" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label Font="Arial" TextColor="White" Text="6" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="SignalSec5" Source="{local:ImageResource Fusion.Pictures.GreenSignalMaterialOn.png}" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label Font="Arial" TextColor="White" Text="5" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                   </StackLayout>                                        
               </StackLayout>
           </Grid>
       </StackLayout>
   </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

The frame is inside a grid column of an outer layout, and here i just limited to the first two icons since result is the same for multiple identical items stacked vertically. Regardless of many tryouts i've done with Horizontal and Vertical options i always obtain this:

[image: actual result]

The frame sizing with respect to outer layout is correct but not the elements inside. Strange think (at least to me) is that picture looks like being outside of the stacklayout as can be seen by the pink background of the layout. Basically i need the pictures to autofit the layout.

Any hint would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#property) :

**Spans** – configure elements to span across multiple rows or columns.

```
<Label Text="SEC" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
<Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="80" /> 
    <RowDefinition Height="80" /> 
    <RowDefinition Height="80" /> 
    <RowDefinition Height="80" /> 

  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="https://www.warm-glass.co.uk/images/products/20cm-deep-royal-blue-precut-glass-circle-11145052.jpg" />
              <Label Text="6" FontSize="30" TextColor="Gray" /> 
 </StackLayout>

 <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="https://www.warm-glass.co.uk/images/products/20cm-deep-royal-blue-precut-glass-circle-11145052.jpg" />
              <Label Text="4" FontSize="30" TextColor="Gray" /> 
 </StackLayout>            

 <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="https://www.warm-glass.co.uk/images/products/20cm-deep-royal-blue-precut-glass-circle-11145052.jpg" />
              <Label Text="2" FontSize="30" TextColor="Gray" /> 
 </StackLayout>             

 <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="https://www.warm-glass.co.uk/images/products/20cm-deep-royal-blue-precut-glass-circle-11145052.jpg" />
              <Label Text="0" FontSize="30" TextColor="Gray" />    
 </StackLayout>


 <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"
              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
              <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="https://www.warm-glass.co.uk/images/products/20cm-deep-royal-blue-precut-glass-circle-11145052.jpg" />
              <Label Text="5" FontSize="30" TextColor="Gray" /> 
 </StackLayout>           


 <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"
              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
              <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="https://www.warm-glass.co.uk/images/products/20cm-deep-royal-blue-precut-glass-circle-11145052.jpg" />
              <Label Text="3" FontSize="30" TextColor="Gray" />  
 </StackLayout>          

 <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"
              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
              <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="https://www.warm-glass.co.uk/images/products/20cm-deep-royal-blue-precut-glass-circle-11145052.jpg" />
              <Label Text="1" FontSize="30" TextColor="Gray" />  
 </StackLayout> 


</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks LeRoy, i tried with grid and now pictures are scaling also without the height and width request. Is there a reason why they don't scale when using stack layouts as  they do in grid. Also, if i remove the width request from image the label is cutted on the right side, so horizontal stack layout is still not compressing the image to give enough space to label. I would expect stacklayout to distribute content equally to ensure that it is all visible.

Comment: @apic , it should scale correctly with StackLayout you just need to specify HeightRequest and set AspectFit on your image. Grids tend to re-render content after build , StackLayout do not dynamically re-render / scale after you Initialize it

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help. Now with Grid layout it's behaving exactly as expected.